# Is it possible to refer to another field in an object expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to refer to another field in an object expression in javascript?

Those ways are not possible:

```
{ a:3, b:a+7 } // a is not defined
{ a:3, b:this.a+7 } // b === NaN
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. Properties aren't variables, and objects aren't namespaces.

Comment: `this` is only set automatically in methods, not objects.